# Keep user input in TextFormFields persistent when Navigating back and forth between screens in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test, textformfield, flutter-form-builder

I'm new to flutter and any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have two separate forms on two different screens. Clicking the 'next' button validates the form and runs `Navigator.push()` to my next screen with the second form, after which if I fill out the TextFormFields of the second form and initialise a save then `Navigator.pop()` to go back to the first form, the data in the first page is still filled out which is intended however once I run Navigator.push() again to go back to the second form the TextFormFields are empty.

**My intention is to have the user data entered in the `TextFormFields` of both forms persistent after Navigating back and forth through different screens.**

I tried using `initialValue` on the TextFormFields but that didn't work.

To Navigate back I'm using the back button automatically created after I run `Navigator.push`

Here is the first page:

```
import '../screens/contact_details_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class PersonalDetailsForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PersonalDetailsFormState createState() => _PersonalDetailsFormState();
}

class _PersonalDetailsFormState extends State<PersonalDetailsForm> {
  String _title;
  String _firstName;
  String _middleName;
  String _surname;
  String _age;
  String _gender;
  String _dateOfBirth;

  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();
  TextEditingController _date = new TextEditingController();

  final GlobalKey<FormState> _personalDetailsFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  Widget _buildTitle() {
    return DropdownButtonFormField(
      items: [
        DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: 'Dr',
          child: Text('Dr'),
        ),
        DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: 'Miss',
          child: Text('Miss'),
        ),
        DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: 'Mr',
          child: Text('Mr'),
        ),
        DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: 'Mrs',
          child: Text('Mrs'),
        ),
        DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: 'Ms',
          child: Text('Ms'),
        ),
        DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: 'Prof.',
          child: Text('Prof.'),
        ),
        DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: 'Sir',
          child: Text('Sir'),
        ),
      ],
      validator: (String value) {
        if (value == null) {
          return 'Title is required';
        }
        return null;
      },
      value: _title,
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Title'),
      onChanged: (String value) {
        setState(() {
          _title = value;
        });
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildFirstName() {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'First Name'),
      keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
      validator: (String value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return 'First name is required';
        }
        return null;
      },
      onSaved: (String value) {
        _firstName = value;
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildMiddleName() {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Middle Name'),
      keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
      onSaved: (String value) {
        _middleName = value;
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSurname() {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Surname Name'),
      keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
      validator: (String value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Surname name is required';
        }
        return null;
      },
      onSaved: (String value) {
        _surname = value;
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildAge() {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Age'),
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      validator: (String value) {
        int age = int.tryParse(value);

        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Age is required';
        }
        if (age == null || age <= 0) {
          return 'Invalid age';
        }
        return null;
      },
      onSaved: (String value) {
        _age = value;
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildGender() {
    return DropdownButtonFormField(
      items: [
        DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: 'Male',
          child: Text('Male'),
        ),
        DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: 'Female',
          child: Text('Female'),
        ),
        DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: 'Other',
          child: Text('Other'),
        )
      ],
      validator: (String value) {
        if (value == null) {
          return 'Gender is required';
        }
        return null;
      },
      value: _gender,
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Gender'),
      onChanged: (String value) {
        setState(() {
          _gender = value;
        });
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildDateOfBirth() {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Date of Birth'),
      validator: (String value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Date of birth is required';
        }
        return null;
      },
      onTap: () {
        // Below line stops keyboard from appearing
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
        // Show Date Picker Here
        _selectDate(context);
      },
      controller: _date,
    );
  }

  Future<Null> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    DateFormat formatter =
        DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy'); //specifies day/month/year format

    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: selectedDate,
        firstDate: DateTime(1900),
        lastDate: DateTime.now());
    if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate)
      setState(() {
        selectedDate = picked;
        _date.value = TextEditingValue(text: formatter.format(picked));
        _dateOfBirth = _date.text;
      });
  }

  void nextScreen(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (_) {
        return ContactDetailsScreen();
      },
    ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(24),
      child: Form(
        key: _personalDetailsFormKey,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              _buildTitle(),
              _buildFirstName(),
              _buildMiddleName(),
              _buildSurname(),
              _buildAge(),
              _buildGender(),
              _buildDateOfBirth(),
              SizedBox(
                height: 50,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: double.infinity,
                child: RaisedButton(
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (!_personalDetailsFormKey.currentState.validate()) {
                      return;
                    }

                    _personalDetailsFormKey.currentState.save();

                    nextScreen(context);
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'Next',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the second page:

```
import 'package:fact_find_v2/screens/testscreen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ContactDetailsForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ContactDetailsFormState createState() => _ContactDetailsFormState();
}

class _ContactDetailsFormState extends State<ContactDetailsForm> {
  String _email;
  String _phoneNumber;
  String _address;

  final GlobalKey<FormState> _contactDetailsFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  Widget _buildEmail() {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      validator: (String value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Email is required';
        }
        if (!RegExp(
                r"[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?")
            .hasMatch(value)) {
          return 'Please enter a valid email address';
        }
        return null;
      },
      onSaved: (String value) {
        _email = value;
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPhoneNumber() {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Phone Number'),
      keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
      validator: (String value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Phone number is required';
        }
        if (!RegExp(r'(^(?:[+0]9)?[0-9]{8,10}$)').hasMatch(value)) {
          return 'Please enter a valid phone number';
        }
        return null;
      },
      onSaved: (String value) {
        _phoneNumber = value;
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildAddress() {
    return TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Address'),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.streetAddress,
        // initialValue: _addressController.text,
        validator: (String value) {
          if (value.isEmpty) {
            return 'Address is required';
          }
          return null;
        },
        onSaved: (String value) {
          _address = value;
        });
  }

  void nextScreen(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (_) {
          return TestScreen();
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(24),
      child: Form(
        key: _contactDetailsFormKey,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              _buildEmail(),
              _buildPhoneNumber(),
              _buildAddress(),
              SizedBox(
                height: 50,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: double.infinity,
                child: RaisedButton(
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (!_contactDetailsFormKey.currentState.validate()) {
                      return;
                    }
                    _contactDetailsFormKey.currentState.save();
                    nextScreen(
                        context); //this is the next screen which is just used for debugging
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'Next',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check the Flutter docs [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/push.html), you can see that the `Navigator.push()` method returns an instance of `Future<T>`.
When you call `Navigator.pop()` from second screen, this will complete the `Future` for the `Navigator.push()` method.

So basically you can return the form data on the second screen back to the first screen and then while pushing the second screen again you can pass that data to the second screen.

**Here's how you can do it -**

1. Add a new `Map` variable to `_PersonalDetailsFormState` screen to save the result for `Navigator.push()` like so -

   ```
   Map<String, Object> contactDetailsResult = Map();
   ```
2. You can save the result returned by the `Navigator.push()` method into a `contactDetailsResult`  and then pass that result as arguments to the `ContactDetailsScreen`.

   ```
   void nextScreen(BuildContext context) async{
     contactDetailsResult = await Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
       builder: (_) {
         return ContactDetailsScreen(
             email: contactDetailsResult["email"] ?? "",
             phoneNumber: contactDetailsResult["phoneNumber"] ?? "",
             address: contactDetailsResult["address"] ?? "",
         );
       },
     ));
   }
   ```
3. For popping the route, you will now have to manually add a button either to the app bar  or use `WillPopScope`. More on that can be found [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html). When popping the route, you need to pass the data from your form like this, which will be saved in the `contactDetailsResult` variable from the previous step -

   ```
   Navigator.of(context).pop({
     "email": email,
     "phoneNumber": phoneNumber,
     "address": address,
   });
   ```
4. You can find a similar example in the official flutter docs [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data).

**Also, one thing to note -**

> This solution does not persist the data in the app. If you pop the first screen then both the forms will be reset. If you wish to persist the data across the app then you should check out the [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) plugin. Tutorial can be found [here](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/using-sharedpreferences-in-flutter-251755f07127).