# Persist Data in TextFormFields between pages

Tags: flutter, dart, textformfield

I am new-ish to flutter and I have come across a problem and I would really appreciate your help.

I have two separate forms on two different screens. Clicking the "Next" button on the first page validates the form and pushes to the second page using `Navigator.push()`. And all works fine until I come back to the first page using the arrow on the top left corner in the app bar which is automatically created. The data inside the TextFormFields on the first page is still filled out which is good but when I click next (which validates and pushes to the second page using `Navigator.push`) and go to the second page all the data inside the TextFormFields has disappeared.

**My intention is to have the user data entered in the `TextFormFields` of both forms persistent after Navigating back and forth through different screens.**

I have already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65573367/keep-user-input-in-textformfields-persistent-when-navigating-back-and-forth-betw) stackoverflow page but the solution there did not fix my issue.
I looked into shared_preferences but the people on the Flutter discord suggested not to use it.

Here is the code:

[First Page](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Zs8Tt79BJx/)

[Second Page](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/3T7S2GDff9/)

(I used PasteUbuntu for the code as it was a bit too long so I didn't want to copy it in this post)

This is the definition for my `formField()` function:

```dart
class formField extends StatelessWidget {
  Function validator;
  Function onSaved;
  String fieldTitle;
  String hintText;
  TextEditingController textController;
  TextInputType keyboardStyle;

  formField(
      {this.onSaved,
      this.validator,
      this.fieldTitle,
      this.hintText,
      this.textController,
      this.keyboardStyle});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        RichText(
          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          text: TextSpan(
              text: fieldTitle,
              style: GoogleFonts.questrial(
                fontSize: 16,
                color: Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              )),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10),
        Container(
          width: 335,
          height: 50,
          child: Material(
            elevation: 5.0,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            child: TextFormField(
              validator: validator,
              onSaved: onSaved,
              textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.bottom,
              textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
              keyboardType: keyboardStyle,
              controller: textController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                filled: true,
                fillColor: Color(0xFFF0F0F0),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFE8E8E8))),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFE8E8E8)),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                ),
                hintText: hintText,
                hintStyle:
                    GoogleFonts.inter(color: Color(0xFFBDBDBD), fontSize: 16),
              ),
              style: GoogleFonts.inter(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can explore the use of [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) to manage data from anywhere in the app. An [example](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) is also provided in the official Flutter docs.

Comment: @Omatt I looked into the provider package and watching a couple videos I sort of understood it but one of the things that still confused me was how that was going to help with the data not disappearing from the textfields in the second page. I haven't able to find an answer for that anywhere online.

Comment: Hi Satvik Garg, Welcome to StackOverflow. I see you are new to flutter. This definitely looks like a state management issue. All your forms should show data from your store behind. Provider/Bloc/Redux offer different solutions for this. Once you start managing your state behind the scenes, you will not lose data in your second page.

Comment: Hi @Amsakanna, I see what you mean for using Provider. Would something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hr_-EqUR0lA&ab_channel=AndyJulow) work for my issue. If I did that for every single page? Also I still don't understand where the data from the `textformfields` will be stored? 

And then what do you mean by this line:
`All your forms should show data from your store behind.`

Thank you!